# Why $http.get to the Json(new MyComlexObject...) web api controller return object Object?

Tags: angularjs, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I got simple web api

```
[HttpGet]
        public JsonResult<LocationDataObject> GetLocationData(string absPath)
        {
            var subdirectoriesInfos = GetDirectoryInfos(absPath);
            var response = new LocationDataObject(
                    new List<DirectoryInfo>(subdirectoriesInfos.Where(si => si.CalculateSize() <= 100000).Select(si => si)),
                    new List<DirectoryInfo>(subdirectoriesInfos.Where(si => (si.CalculateSize() > 100000 && si.CalculateSize() < 500000)).Select(si => si)),
                    new List<DirectoryInfo>(subdirectoriesInfos.Where(si => si.CalculateSize() > 10000000).Select(si => si)),
                    GetFileInfos(absPath));
            return Json(response);
        }.
```

When I do this:

```
$http.get('api/browsingdata/GetLocationData?absPath=' + currentLocation.FullPath)
                .then(
                    function (response) {
                        $scope.subdirectories_1 = response.data.Lt10mb;
                        $scope.subdirectories_2 = response.data.Between10mbAnd50mb;
                        $scope.subdirectories_2 = response.data.Gt100mb;

                        alert(response);
});
```

the result is `object Object` which has no properties of `LocationDataObject`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: better is to use "console.log(response);" than alert(response), you will able to get idea, and don't forget to see "console"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `LocationDataObject` is Object and that is why it shows `[object object]` .

if you want to use `LocationDataObject` as property, then use

```
var response = new{LocationDataObject = new LocationDataObject(
                    new List<DirectoryInfo>(subdirectoriesInfos.Where(si => si.CalculateSize() <= 100000).Select(si => si)),
                    new List<DirectoryInfo>(subdirectoriesInfos.Where(si => (si.CalculateSize() > 100000 && si.CalculateSize() < 500000)).Select(si => si)),
                    new List<DirectoryInfo>(subdirectoriesInfos.Where(si => si.CalculateSize() > 10000000).Select(si => si)),
                    GetFileInfos(absPath))
};
return Json(response);
```

then you can use

```
response.LocationDataObject
```

if you still confuse, put debug point or do `console.log(response);` instead of `alert` and check on console

Answer (score 0):

I guess `object Object` is printed to the alert. Or you might need to clarify your question.

Objects will be stringified in alerts, therefore any object without a `toString()` method will be displayed as `object Object`. If must, use `console.log` to print your response, as it will show you the actual object, not the stringified object.